# I downloaded a newer version of Jest and now my react app won't open

Tags: node.js, shell, react-native, jestjs

I am trying to learn React Native and I downloaded Jest to help me test apps. I didn't realize that React automatically downloaded Jest. Now if I run `cd react-app/ [return] npm start [return]`, my command prompt blows up with errors. It basically says that I should have Jest v24.7.1 but I have 24.8.0 . I am not sure what to do to be able to open my react app.

In a different program, I followed the steps below, but the issue was recurring.

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.

   2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
   3. Remove "jest" from `dependencies` and/or `devDependencies` in the package.json file in your project folder.
   4. Run `npm install` or `yarn`, depending on the package manager you use.

Create a new react app

Delete all files in the src folder
Create an index.js file
Paste the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

const element = <h1>Hello World</h1>;
ReactDom.render(element, document.getElementById("root"));
```

This should create a "Hello World" page.

I wanted for a new tab to open on my computer with the url of "localhost:3000", but instead the command prompt said:

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

```
"jest": "24.7.1"
```

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of jest was detected higher up in the tree:

C:\Users\krish\node_modules\jest (version: 24.8.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
    This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if C:\Users\krish\node_modules\jest is outside your project directory.
    For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls jest in your project folder.
    This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed jest.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\krish\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-29T20_19_25_440Z-debug.log
```

Comment: what are your `node` and `npm` versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem i solved this like this,

1. write terminal npm uninstall jest
2. go your project folder
3. delete node folder
4. write terminal npm install

Answer (score 0):

If you installed jest globally then you need to delete the node_modules folder from your  C:\Users\krish location in your computer.